# How to connect from pgAdmin to Postgresql in Kubernetes/Minikube

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I run a local kubernetes cluster (Minikube) and I try to connect pgAdmin to postgresql, bot run in Kubernetes.
What would be the connection string? Shall I access by service ip address or by service name?

```
kubectl get service

    NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
    dbpostgresql      NodePort    10.103.252.31   <none>        5432:30201/TCP   19m
    kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          3d21h
    pgadmin-service   NodePort    10.109.58.168   <none>        80:30200/TCP     40h

kubectl get ingress:

    NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
    pgadmin-ingress   <none>   *       192.168.49.2   80      40h

kubectl get pod:

    NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    pgadmin-5569ddf4dd-49r8f    1/1     Running   1          40h
    postgres-78f4b5db97-2ngck   1/1     Running   0          23m
```

I have tried with 10.103.252.31:30201 but without success.

Comment: Both pgadmin and postgresql are running inside cluster. Shouldn't it  be accessible by ip?

Comment: Ah, I got it. Then it should work, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Remember minikube is running inside its' own container, the NodePort clusterIPs you're getting back are open inside of minikube. So to get minikube's resolution of port and ip, run: `minikube service <your-service-name> --url`
This will return something like http://127.0.0.1:50946 which you can use to create an external DB connection. [image]

Another option would be to use kubectl to forward a local port to the service running on localhost ex. `kubectl port-forward service/django-service 8080:80`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the cluster, services can refer to each other by DNS based on Service object names. So in this case you would use `dbpostgresql` or `dbpostgresql.default.svc.cluster.local` as the hostname.

Comment: I have also tried this, but didn't worked.

Comment: You would have to be more specific about the error.

Comment: Error says: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "dbpostgresql" (10.100.155.95) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: If I try with port 30201, error says. "Unable to connect to server. timeout expired" So it might be that postgres does not properly run inside pod.

Comment: Make sure that Postgres is listening on 0.0.0.0 and not localhost.

Comment: I have created a posgres image where I've overwriteen postgresql.conf to have line listen_address='*'. This should allow connection from any client. I still get 'Unable to connect to server.' I am still not sure weather the problem is inside kubernetes cluster and comunication or there is a problem with posgres instance.